# OnDrawerItemClickListener Does not work.

Tags: java, android, fragment, navigation-drawer

I have been working on this navigation drawer with toolbar.Now am stuck with the click listener. When i click the items in the drawer it does nothing. My class is fragment. Here its the code.
    package com.vivek.ss;

```
import android.app.FragmentManager;
import android.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;

import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.Drawer;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.PrimaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.SecondaryDrawerItem;
import com.mikepenz.materialdrawer.model.interfaces.IDrawerItem;


public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

   private BaseFragment mBaseFragment;
   private int mSelectedFragment;
   private static String BUNDLE_SELECTEDFRAGMENT = "Selected";
   private static final int CASE_START = 0;
   private static final int CASE_VIEW = 1;


    private Drawer.Result result = null;

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putInt(BUNDLE_SELECTEDFRAGMENT , mSelectedFragment);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        final Toolbar toolbar;

        toolbar = (Toolbar)findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            mSelectedFragment = savedInstanceState.getInt(BUNDLE_SELECTEDFRAGMENT);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            if (fragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.frame_container) == null)
                mBaseFragment = selectFragment(mSelectedFragment);

        }

        result = new Drawer().withActivity(this).withToolbar(toolbar).withActionBarDrawerToggle(true).withHeader(R.layout.header)
                .addDrawerItems(new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.primaryfirst)

                        , new PrimaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.primarysecond),
                        new SecondaryDrawerItem().withName(R.string.secondaryfirst)


                ).withOnDrawerItemClickListener(new Drawer.OnDrawerItemClickListener() {

                   @Override
                   public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id, IDrawerItem iDrawerItem) {
                       if (iDrawerItem != null) {

                           if (iDrawerItem instanceof PrimaryDrawerItem) {
                               toolbar.setTitle(((PrimaryDrawerItem) iDrawerItem).getNameRes());
                               mBaseFragment = selectFragment(position);
                               mSelectedFragment = position;
                           }


                       }



                   }

  }).build();




    }

    private BaseFragment selectFragment(int position) {


        BaseFragment baseFragment = null;

        switch (position) {
            case CASE_START:
                baseFragment = new TestFragment();
                break;
            case CASE_VIEW:
                baseFragment = new TestFragment();
                break;
        }
        return baseFragment;
    }


 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


    }
```

Comment: Is `onItemClick` method is executing ?

Comment: Yes. clicking on the items it changes the action bar title correspondingly.
But my fragment wont start :(

Comment: It works great. Now i have the cardview list when i click the start capture. :)

Comment: Hello , Am new to this great site. but i have been checking it out this site more often. Only thing i was not posting.
Thanks for reminding me. I have done it now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> clicking on the items it changes the action bar title correspondingly.
>   But my fragment wont start

To display Fragment on onItemClick need to use `replace` or `add` methods of FragmentTransaction. start Fragment as from `onItemClick` method:

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.frame_container, mBaseFragment);  
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
// Commit the transaction
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```